# Adding an class to body element with XDV

Tags: plone, diazo, xdv, plone-3.x, deliverance

I want to style some forms in Plone3+collective.xdv but I don't want all forms to get the special style.

So I'd like to add a special `styled-form` class name  to the `class` attribute of the `body` element just when displaying certain templates:

- contact-info
- sendto_form
- PFG forms

So I thought that I could manage to perform this with XDV in order not to modify those templates.

By using the `if-content` directives in XDV rules I can check if those templates are being displayed:

```
css:if-content="body.template-contact-info"
```

for instance.

But I don't find the way to **keep the class attribute** as delivered by Plone and **add the special class** based on that condition.

My desired result would be something like:

```
<body class="template-contact-info styled-form">
    ...
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Diazo/plone.app.theming you can merge attributes from the template and content, see: http://diazo.org/basic.html#merge

If you can't upgrade then you'll need to do this with inline XSL, something like:

```
<prepend theme="/html/body" css:if-content="body.template-contact-info"><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="/html/body/@class"/> styled-form</xsl:attribute></prepend>
```

**Update:** I forgot the  tag in the example above. It should work now.

Comment: This *almost* works. It adds the a text node with the resulting values: ``<body class="template-contact-info" dir="ltr">template-contact-info styled-form ... `` How can I tell XDV to insert that inside the ``class`` attribute?

Comment: I think you can get that with: <append theme="/html/body/@class" css:if-content="body.template-contact-info"><xsl:value-of select="/html/body/@class"/> styled-form</append>

Comment: @davi-lima: no, apparently ``theme`` doesn't accept attributes but whole elements. I think that the ``merge`` rule of Diazo should workd. But I don't have diazo, but collective.xdv