# Diazo - Conditionally add a class to a theme element

Tags: xslt, diazo

I need to add a class to an element coming from the theme only if certain conditions are met.  I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599993/adding-an-class-to-body-element-with-xdv), adjusted for Diazo by replacing `prepend` with `before`:

```
<before css:theme=".main" if-content="not(//*[@id='portal-column-two'])"><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="//*[@class='main']/@class"/> full</xsl:attribute></before>
```

but I get the following error:

```
XSLTApplyError: xsl:attribute: Cannot add attributes to an element if children have been already added to the element.
```

I get that error even when I remove all other rules such that there is only the `<theme>` rule and the `<before>` rule.

How can I add a class to a theme element only when there is no `#portal-column-two` element in the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Diazo replacement for `prepend css:theme` is `before css:theme-children`, not `before css:theme`. Your example works with that changed.