# How to compute an href value with Diazo rules

Tags: diazo

I am trying to change the `href`s of certain `<a>` elements in the theme by computing the URLs using values I select from the content.  However, I can't figure out how to change the href attribute at all.  It seems like the `attributes` attribute is not understood in the `<replace>` rule.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
<replace css:theme="a.languageswitcher" attributes="href">
  <!-- use some XSL logic here to stitch together the new href -->
</replace>
```

So the following rules work, but are useless to me:

```
<copy attributes="href" css:theme="a.languageswitcher" css:content="#portal-logo" />

<merge attributes="href" css:theme="a.languageswitcher" css:content="#portal-logo" />
```

But this one already does not work, the `attributes="href"` makes it so this rule is ignored.

```
<replace attributes="href" css:theme="a.languageswitcher" css:content="#portal-logo" />
```

On the other hand, if I try to rebuild the `<a>` element from scratch, then I run into the error described by @ross-patterson in his question: [Diazo - Conditionally add a class to a theme element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131092/diazo-conditionally-add-a-class-to-a-theme-element):

```
    <replace theme="//a[@class='languageswitcher']">
      <a class="languageswitcher">
        <xsl:attribute name='href'>
          foo
        </xsl:attribute>
      </a>
    </replace>
```

produces the error:

```
XSLTApplyError: xsl:attribute: Cannot add attributes to an element if children have been already added to the element.
```

How can this be done?

Comment: This is really tricky IMO.... faced with the same problem & after a lot of trying, I gave up and just made sure the link was somewhere in my Plone content so I could use a <copy> rule to pull it in

Answer (score 3):

Something like this ought to work:

```
<replace css:theme="a.languageswitcher">
    <xsl:for-each css:select="a.languageswitcher">
        <xsl:variable name="link">
            http://example.com
        </xsl:variable>
        <a href="{$link}"><xsl:copy-of select="." /></a>
    </xsl:for-each>
</replace>
```

Comment: This does not work for me either.  It completely erases the `<a>` elements.  A couple things:  the variable `link` is hard-coded in your example, I want it to come from the content.  Also, I'm not sure what the `for-each` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

in a theme I used this rule

```
<replace css:content-children="#hptoolbar-cerca"><xsl:attribute name="href">
<xsl:value-of select="//li[@id='portaltab-catalog']//a/@href" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></replace>
```

to modify an href of #hptoolbar-cerca with the href from another element in the content.

Maybe this could be useful for you.

Vito

Comment: This is the closest I could get so far  

        `<replace css:theme-children=".languageswitcher">
          <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="//a[@id='portal-logo']/@href" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        </replace>`

It correctly replaces the href of the `<a>` element, but it also erases the text inside.

Answer (score 0):

My case is similar. I am happy with my theme code, only want to "replace" its `href` values. With XPath copied in the Chrome inspector, the simplest rule looks like this:

```
<copy attributes="href"
       theme="/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a"
     content="//*[@id='portal-logo']" />
```

I expect to successfully apply this trick to all the `href` values, but some do not work. I find these `<a>` elements are in the code block manipulated by JavaScript for implementing Slide effect. I remove all its related JavaScript codes, and copy its "real" XPath again, finally everything works fine as expected. Hope this helpful.