# Add class to body tag using diazo with theme is enabled

Tags: xslt, plone, diazo

I wonder how I can add a class to body tag using Diazo with theme is set. 
I'll use `if-content` to check if the `portal-column-two` exist or not and depending on this put a class into body tag.

One solution is:

```
<replace theme="/html/body/@class">
  <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:copy-of select="." /> three_col</xsl:attribute>
</replace>
```

and is described here:
[Add class to body tag using diazo with notheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672440/add-class-to-body-tag-using-diazo-with-notheme) but works only if notheme is set.

So how can I put a simple additional css class into the body tag on the fly?

EDIT:
This works with pure Diazo with theme and in Plone (plone.app.theming):

```
<before theme-children="/html/body"><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="/html/body/@class" /> three_col</xsl:attribute>
</before>
```

And based on condition:

```
<before theme-children="/html/body" css:if-content="#portal-column-two">
  <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="/html/body/@class" /> three_col</xsl:attribute>
</before>
<before theme-children="/html/body" css:if-not-content="#portal-column-two">
  <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="/html/body/@class" /> two_col</xsl:attribute>
</before>
```

My final solution is described here: https://plone-theming-with-diazo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/snippets_diazo/recipes/index.html#add-css-class-depending-on-existing-portal-columns

Comment: Little related, here is how add body classes with Python: http://developer.plone.org/templates_css_and_javascripts/css.html#adding-new-css-body-classes

Comment: hi Mikko, thx for your answer but i was looking for pure Diazo/XSLT solution.

Comment: I wonder - isn't this question answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution used by @MrTango is described here: https://plone-theming-with-diazo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/snippets_diazo/recipes/index.html#add-css-class-depending-on-existing-portal-columns